# How to remove all checked items in Notes?

Tags: ios, notes.app

How can I remove all checked items in Notes on iOS easily? From e.g. a grocery list, I want to remove all items (checkbox and text) that have been checked with a simple action.

I think I did this once, but I have forgotten how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This method will delete all the checked lines in a selection:

- Highlight/select the checklist items or entire block containing the items you want to delete.
- Click on the highlighted selection to display the context menu.
- In the context menu, click the arrow (>) until you see the “Checklist” option. Click ”Checklist”.
- The context menu will update. Select “Delete Checked”.